# How can a bytes32[] variable have a custom method (i.e., verifyCalldata)?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, calldata, merkle, method

Code: https://www.contractreader.io/contract/mainnet/0x0C7D4bdA40CF78F9F1BAf6e3D5774f1E22c9CC4B

My question is about this `verifyCalldata()` call:

```
    function verifyAddress(
        uint256 _projectId,
        bytes32[] calldata _proof,
        address _address
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        return
            _proof.verifyCalldata(
                projectMerkleRoot[_projectId],
                hashAddress(_address)
            );
    }
```

If `_proof` is a `bytes32[]`, how can it have the method `verifyCalldata()`?

`bytes32[]` is an array of bytes, right?

I see verifyCalldata() in `@openzeppelin-4.7/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol` and it's signature is:

```
library MerkleProof {
...
    function verifyCalldata(
        bytes32[] calldata proof,
        bytes32 root,
        bytes32 leaf
    ) internal pure returns (bool) {
        ...
```

So I would expect the call to be something like:

```
return MerkleProof.verifyCalldata(
     merkleProof,
     merkleRoot,
     leaf
);
```

but it is not. Why?

I feel like there's some magic (or shorthand) I haven't learned yet.

Comment: A better title might be "How can a function with 3 parameters, be called with only 2 arguments?"  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is the `using A for B` directive at [line 59](https://etherscan.io/address/0x0C7D4bdA40CF78F9F1BAf6e3D5774f1E22c9CC4B#code#F19#L59):

```
using MerkleProof for bytes32[];
```

With that operation, you ask Solidity to consider all the methods it finds in the `MerkleProof` library, having a `byte32[]` as a first parameter, as valid methods of any `byte32[]` variable.

So, after that line, for example, all the following functions are valid methods for any `byte32[]` variable:

```
function verifyCalldata(bytes32[] calldata proof, bytes32 root, bytes32 leaf) internal pure returns (bool);
function processProofCalldata(bytes32[] calldata proof, bytes32 leaf) internal pure returns (bytes32);
...
```

As an additional trick, Solidity passes the same variable as the method's first parameter so that the following two syntaxes become equivalent.

```
// with `using MerkleProof for bytes32[];`
return _proof.verifyCalldata(projectMerkleRoot[_projectId], hashAddress(_address));

// without `using MerkleProof for bytes32[];`
return MerkleProof.verifyCalldata(_proof, projectMerkleRoot[_projectId], hashAddress(_address));
```

You can read more about the use of the `using A for B` directive in the [official Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/contracts.html#using-for).

As a side note, library syntax is convenient for clarifying the code, but using it here seems an unnecessary overdesigned magic trick; it introduces misunderstanding instead of making things clearer.

The syntax you expected is the one that makes the most sense to me, so don't take this contract as an example. I suggest developing your contract so that lines of code are straightforward, not *stylish*.